# Networkx: How to visually group a set of nodes

Tags: python, networkx

I would like to visually group a set of nodes in networkx. Of course one could do so by changing node color, size etc. My preferred solution however should look something like the plot created with igraph below. Is this possible in networkx?

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541376/how-to-draw-communities-with-networkx/43541777#43541777) similar to what you are looking for?

Comment: It is hard to understand your requirement from your question. What do you mean by `visually group a set of nodes`? Do you run any algorithm first to find the community? Also you didn't share your work here. What you have done so far?